how to create a query of action to fetch data in react
I have a Person component in my react app to get detail personal information from a API endpoint by email address:
const Person = ({ email }) => {
    const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState();

    const { callApi } = useUtils();

    const getUser = async ({ email }) => {
        let profile = localStorage.getItem("Person:" + email)
        if (!profile) {
            const response = await callApi({
                endpoint: `WebPage/GetUserProfile?Email=${email}`,
                method: "GET"
            });
            setUserProfile(response);
            localStorage.setItem("Person:" + email, JSON.stringify(response))
        }
        else {
            setUserProfile(JSON.parse(profile))
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getUser({ email: email });
    }, [])

    return (
        !userProfile ? (
            <span>{email}</span>
        ) : (
            <span title={userProfile.Email}>{userProfile.Name}</span>
        )
    )
}

export default Person;

It is used in many place in my webapp and they are all good, but now I want to use it in a table to convert email address data to detail person profile, so I insert this Person component in each row.  here is my table:
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {currentItems.map(item => (
            <tr key={item.ApprovalId}>
                <td>{item.Title}</td>
                <td><Person email={item.TicketCreatedByEmail} /></td>
                <td>
                    <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        onClick={() => viewDetail(item.SignTicketId, item.ApprovalId)}
                    >Open</Button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ))}
    </tbody>
</table>

and now the problem is every time when this table load, it will fire fetch request to my API for each row, although there are same person in different row. for example, I have this table from data source:
|      Title    |          Created By       |   Action  |
|---------------|---------------------------|-----------|
|      test1    |        alice@demo.com     |           |
|      test2    |        bob@demo.com       |           |
|      test3    |        alice@demo.com     |           |
|      test4    |        bob@demo.com       |           |
|      test5    |        bob@demo.com       |           |
|      test6    |        alice@demo.com     |           |

there are only 2 person in this table, Alice and Bob.  Ideally there should be only 2 requests go to backend API, and use cached result in local storage for rest of row.  but what really happened are 6 requests for all the rows, and request duplicated data.  I'm wondering if there is a query or similar way to improve the performance of this case?  Thank you.

Same comment as per last time... It sounds like you should make a single API call to hydrate all the profiles for currentItems in the parent component but we don't know if that's even an option

Reuse doesn't always guarantee efficiency - if you need something, make it new!

Why not call a batch API with unique emails? Get the person list and render it as rows?

@Phil  the previous post is closed and not open after I edit it, so I think maybe it's better to submit a new one.   Does React-Query help this?  if I create 2 same request in the same time, will it hold one until the other one return and reuse the cache?

Try the useMemo and useCallback functions to prevent excess rendering. I would also suggest not using useEffect here, since you can replicate your intended behavior buy putting the source in the function and wrapping with the memo and/or callback hooks when needed.

Ideally you should create an API endpoint that can resolve all the user profile data for any collection of currentItems.
But without changing anything around your backend, the best you can hope for is to pre-populate the profiles for currentItems with as few requests as possible.
For example, create functions to get items and populate them with profile data
// These are best defined in their own module, outside your components
const STORAGE_KEY_PREFIX = 'Person:';

const getUser = async (email) => {
  const key = STORAGE_KEY_PREFIX + email;
  let profile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  if (!profile) {
    profile = await callApi({
      endpoint: `WebPage/GetUserProfile?Email=${encodeURIComponent(email)}`,
      method: 'GET',
    });
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(response));
  }
  return profile;
};

const getItemsAndProfiles = async () => {
  // assuming you already have something like this
  const items = await getItems(); 

  // get unique emails
  const emails = new Set(items.map((item) => item.TicketCreatedByEmail));

  // create a map of email to profile, eg
  // {
  //   "alice@demo.com": { Name: "Alice", ... },
  //   "bob@demo.com": { Name: "Bob", ... },
  // }
  const profiles = Object.fromEntries(
    await Promise.all(
      Array.from(emails, async (email) => [email, await getUser(email)]),
    ),
  );

  // return items pre-populated with profile data
  return items.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    UserProfile: profiles[item.TicketCreatedByEmail],
  }));
};

Then in your component, use this to load currentItems and pass each item.UserProfile to your <Person> component.
const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  getItemsAndProfiles().then(setCurrentItems).catch(console.error);
}, []);

// ...

<tbody>
  {currentItems.map(item => (
    <tr key={item.ApprovalId}>
      <td>{item.Title}</td>
      <td>
        <Person profile={item.UserProfile} />
      </td>
      <td>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          onClick={() => viewDetail(item.SignTicketId, item.ApprovalId)}
        >Open</Button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>

